# HTTP ERROR 500 when object is cached in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My website was working fine for weeks, I made no changes to the code/server and today I noticed that I am getting `HTTP ERROR 500` and occasionally `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 31424352 bytes)` on one of the pages on my website with the following controller code:

```
$builds = Cache::remember(
'All.builds.page.' . $currentPage . ".by." . $sortBy,
now()->addSeconds(30),
function () use ($sortBy) {
    if ($sortBy == 'top') {
        return Build::where('private', 0)->has('ratings', '>=', 5)->with(['user', 'hunter', 'ratings', 'views'])->withCount(['ratings as average' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(\DB::raw('coalesce(avg(value), 0)'));
        }])->orderByDesc('average')->paginate(15)->onEachSide(1);
    }
    return Build::where('private', 0)->with(['user', 'hunter', 'ratings', 'views'])->orderBy($sortBy, 'DESC')->paginate(15)->onEachSide(1);
});
```

This happens when `$sortBy` is set to `top` and when the object has been cached. For example, if I visit the page for the first time it will return the top rated builds. If I refresh the page, I will see the error. I have to wait 30 seconds for the cache to expire or manually clear the cache for the page to work again.

The website has handled 10 times the traffic it is having right now without any issues and now all of a sudden it's not working. Does someone know why this is happening and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: If the error occurs only when the object is cached, then it is outside the closure function and the code you provided is irrelevant, it could be either the `$currentPage` or `$sortBy` variables, but it would be great if you include the mysterious 500 HTTP Error from your logs in your question :)

Comment: @Saly3301 this is what the error log says: `[Mon Oct 14 21:35:31.027450 2019] [php7:error] [pid 8028] [client **IP**] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to llocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/html/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php on line 190, referer: https://example.com/builds?sort=top`

Comment: Which driver are you using for caching?

Comment: It's in the error: FileStore.php

Comment: @Muki, as Saly mentioned, you are storing a lot of data in the cache. Is there a way you can recode that part of the app to store only what's needed in the cache, or maybe in multiple pieces? Do you absolutely need all those relationships?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to cache a large dataset into one file and memory got exhausted when the database grew, since this code uses eager loading, more data will be cached

```php
return Build::where('private', 0)->has('ratings', '>=', 5)->with([
        'user', 'hunter', 'ratings', 'views'
    ])->withCount(['ratings as average' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(\DB::raw('coalesce(avg(value), 0)'));
}])->orderByDesc('average')->paginate(15)->onEachSide(1);
```

You can either try to minimize the result or increase the allowed memory limit in the `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini` file from half a gigabyte to 2 gigabytes or more depending on your needs

From

```
; memory_limit = 512M
```

To

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```

> ## temporary increase the limit to debug your issue, and be aware, doing so can cause your server to run out of RAM and taking down your application

Hope this helps

Comment: i don't want to be harsh or rude in any way, but i do not think the solution is to bump the memory limit to 2GB. I understand RAM is cheap, and some servers have plenty. But the idea is to fix the underlying error or find other ways to solve the problem, not just throw more RAM at it.

Comment: It's a temporary solution for a 500 error in a production server, good luck optimizing a query with no access to models, tables and data

Comment: Ok, you should add in your response the following: `temporary increase the limit to debug your issue`, and `be aware, doing so can cause your server to run out of RAM and taking down your application`. I think that's just appropriate. I also agree with you, he's having WAY to many relationships loaded, each with god knows how many columns.

Comment: And this solution was proposed a gazzilion times on Stack Overflow, you may make a search and lurk around every one of them commenting the same thing

Comment: Edited* happy now?

Comment: I wish I would have 100,000 reputation and time to do that, i would. See, you might understand what implications that have, but 90% of these people don't. They blindly increase the limit and ... leave it like that. Their code WORKS

Comment: Saly, this is not about me being happy, this is about teaching that person something good today. Even though chances are, he will increase that limit and leave it like that for many months.